# open Fragment from FragmentActivity class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I dont know if this is possible.

I have a class which extends Fragment:

```
public class UsesUser extends Fragment {
```

And a class which extends FragmentActivity:

```
public class Uses extends FragmentActivity {
```

When a button is pressed in Uses, I want open UsesUser.

What I usually do is:

```
UsesUser newFragment = new UsesUser();
fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But I dont know how to get fragmentTransaction and fragment.

how can I get this values from a FragmentActivity class?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `FragmentTransaction` this way:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

`fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layout_where_lies_my_fragment));`

Comment: you should try `replace` instead of `hide` and use `pushToBackStack`.